# How can I access a docker web application in a remote linux server directly from my windows local browser?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, remote

Following [a mirror tutorial](https://hub.docker.com/r/mathworks/matlab) on dockerhub, I managed to run a docker web application on a remote Linux service. Here the host is the remote ubuntu server, which can be accessed via the browser address "http://localhost:8888/index.html". In the same way, I built the container with the following command.

```bash
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 --shm-size=512M mathworks/matlab:r2022b -browser
```

However, the problem is that the application can only be accessed from the browser on the host computer, not from my local computer or from a different computer's browser on the same LAN.
I have had a hard time finding a solution by searching the web and trying to access it by specifying the following URL address, but nothing works.

```
"http://localhost:8888/index.html"
"http://<linux_ip_id>:8888/index.html"
"http://<windows_ip_id>:8888/index.html"
"http://<container_ip_id>:8888/index.html"
```

Also, I understand from [other sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814696/how-to-connect-to-a-docker-container-from-outside-the-host-same-network-windo) that I need to set the network method between the host and my local computer to be bridged and its solution is a VM VirtualBox Manager setup. But my case is different, the host is a remote standalone ubuntu server. the docker container communicates with the host by default as a bridge, but I tried to run the docker container by building it with the network connection specified as `--network=host` and the above access address still doesn't work!

Note: My local computer is a windows 10 system, which is on the same LAN as the remote Linux system, i.e. I can ping the server IP address normally, and I can also connect to it via ssh.

Comment: During this time, I also tried to turn off the firewall on the linux server，but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I was able to solve my problem by using the `ssh` command. The reference command for using `ssh` on a local windows system is as follows.
`ssh -L 8888:<remote_linux_ip>:8888 <my_name>@<remote_linux_ip>`

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar situation. Docker running on Linux server VM. Tryed to access docker container remotely from other machine in other network.
Solution was to modify iptables on linux server:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ensXX -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

this command allows connecting from any network.
ensXX - is my linux server network interface (see ifconfig).

after this command was executed I was able to connect to docker container remotely.

more about docker and iptables: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Comment: Unfortunately, my attempts to use your method still did not solve my problem. However, I solved my problem by using the following command in `ssh` on my local windows system.`ssh -L 8888:<remote_linux_ip>:8888 <my_name>@<remote_linux_ip>`